# Deserialize Lua table with NLua

Tags: lua, nlua

I have searched the web and particularly this:

[Table Serialiazation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization)

and none of them work.

I am trying the simplest of tables as follows:

THIS IS THE INPUT.LUA FILE

```
{
    ["customers"] =
    {
        ["name"] = "John Smith",
        ["age"] = 45
    },
    {
        ["name"] = "Susan Jones",
        ["age"] = 34
    },
}
```

Where `x = input.lua`

And I have in my Lua an:-

```
if(type (x) == "table" then
   dostuff()
else
  return "this is not a table"
end
```

And all I get with all the deserializers is the "this is not a table".

I am now writing my own deserializer, which will have to handle all the escaping characters, and the beginning of tables, and the tracking of nested tables and the typing of values - why????

Am I a moron - which part of the table serialiazion routines did I misunderstand??

Comment: I should have added that before I run x through the if statement, I have tried to deserialize it using methods from the Table Serialiazation site.

Comment: You will have to show more code in order for us to help you. Make a MWE (a minimum working example) with the code reduce to the bare minimum. This should contain something around 10 lines, perhaps plus your input data.

Comment: where do you define input.lua which you assign to x?

Comment: Your example would not run due to the improper whitespace and `(`. That aside, what does `print(type(x))` tell you, and what exactly are you defining as `x`?